# React list of elements not scrolling

Tags: list, reactjs, scroll, overflow

I have a div with a list of elements created on the render method of a component. The style of the container has `overflow: scroll` however the scroll doesn't show anything else than the initially visible items. I wonder if this behaviour is expected in react and how to fix it.

```
<div style={{ margin: 15, marginLeft: 35 }}>
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
      <div style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
        Lorem Ipsum
      </div>
      <div style={{ display: 'block', maxWidth: 300, marginLeft: 20, overflow: 'scroll' }}>
        <div> Item visible </div>
        <div> Item visible </div>
        <div> Item visible </div>
        <div> Item visible </div>

        <div> Item NOT visible </div>
        <div> Item NOT visible </div>
        <div> Item NOT visible </div>
        <div> Item NOT visible </div>
        <div> Item NOT visible </div>
        <div> Item NOT visible </div>
        <div> Item NOT visible </div>
        <div> Item NOT visible </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does your parent component have a height set?

Comment: @corvid I've updated the code to a more real one

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using `overflow: 'scroll'` set `overflow: 'auto'`, event if you set the `height` of the parent proper `scroll bar` will come.

Check this example:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(<div style={{ margin: 15, marginLeft: 35 }}>
              <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row' }}>
                <div style={{ marginRight: 10 }}>
                  Lorem Ipsum
                </div>
              <div style={{overflow: 'auto', height: 'inherit', display: 'block', maxWidth: 300, marginLeft: 20,}}>
                <div> Item visible</div>
                <div> Item visible</div>
                <div> Item visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
                <div> Item NOT visible</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: thanks, setting a height to the parent has fixed the issue

Comment: set the parent div a height (e.g: height: 100vh;) made the scroll bar to appear